# Присоединительное значение союза "и"

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться! Есть три примера (взяты из справочника Розенталя):
1) [Лизавета Ивановна] разливала чай, и получала выговоры за лишний расход сахара;
2) она вслух читала романы, и виновата была во всех ошибках автора;
3) она сопровождала графиню в её прогулках, и отвечала за погоду и за мостовую.

Не могу понять, зачем перед союзом "и" ставится запятая?

Answer (score 3):

Некото­рые из союзов (и,да в значении и) употребляются в присоединительном значении. В этом случае они добавляют то, что пришло в голову, когда мысль уже была выс­казана. или же присоединяют неожиданное следствие. Перед союзами с этим значе­нием голос понижается и делается пауза. Перед присоединительными союзами ставится запятая; вместо запятой может быть тире и даже точка.

В этом примере в трёх предложе­ниях союз *и* имеет присоединительное значение. Он присоединяет сказуемое, кото­рое обозначает нечто совсем неожиданное, что никак не вытекает из сказанного.

(https://studopedia.org/12-51725.html)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Теперь всё предельно ясно.