# Требуется ли какой-либо знак перед союзом "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Нам принесли всё лучшее и в каком-то гигантском количестве.

Мне чуется *и* в значении *причём*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, *и* употреблено в присоединительном значении. (см: [Присоединительное значение союза “и”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435707/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B8/435710#435710)).

Следовательно, запятая нужна.

Answer (score 1):

**Обособление факультативное, выбирайте по контексту.**

Например: Нам принесли всё лучшее и в очень большом количестве. Здесь вроде бы запятая не нужна.

Из Нацкорпуса

Причем эти фотографии есть, **и в огромном количестве**. [Александр Журбин. Как это делалось в Америке. Автобиографические заметки (1999)]

Мы читали постоянно и **в огромном количестве**. [Александр Зиновьев. Русская судьба, исповедь отщепенца (1988-1998)]

― Чуда, спаситель!.. Откуда-то взялись ― и в огромном количестве! ― нищие, увечные и блажные калеки...

Comment: Думаю, *постоянно* и *в огромном количестве* - однородные члены, поэтому нет запятой, но вы не найдете однородных членов ни в двух других ваших предложениях, ни в авторском.

Comment: "Она понемногу откладывала деньги и экономила на всем, только цветы у нее были всегда прекрасные и в большом количестве". Это однородные члены?

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что да, оба характеризуют цветы с разных сторон: цветы прекрасные, цветы в большом количестве.

Comment: Ну тогда "всё лучшее и в гигантских количествах" тоже однородные члены. Просто при желании мы можем придать им статус присоединительных отношений, а это зависит от структуры предложения и желания автора.

Comment: Если оба относятся к *принесли*, то мне кажется, в этом случае получается коряво "принесли в каком-то гигантском количестве", в отличие от "принесли все лучшее"

Comment: Интонационно оба варианты равноправны, поэтому надо смотреть, как это предложение вписывается в остальной текст. Нужно ли в этом месте делать остановку, подчеркивая обособленный член, или он того не стоит.